# Keycloak is sending HTML code inside password reset link

Tags: keycloak

Yesterday I started noticing that the keycloak emails for required user actions are containing HTML characters inside the URL that is being sent for the required action.

example: `/auth/realms/EasyDox/login-actions/action-token?key&#61;eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiI`

This of course gives me an error on the keycloak page

[image]

If I change the characters `&#61` to `=` in the URL, it works fine and I am able to do the password reset.

Note that we are using mailjet to send emails through our custom domain.

I really don't know where the issue is since before yesterday everything was working fine, and I'm kind of lost on what to look for.

If anyone has any suggestions what to try since we have customers that are connected to this keycloak, and some of them can't log in since they forgot their password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by moving our mail sending from Mailjet to SendGrid. It had nothing to do with keycloak.